# How to calculate the voltage of the capacitor in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor

i have a problem with this circuit.
I am trying to calculate all the voltages and currents but i think i did something wrong.

I think the voltages \$U_L\$ and \$U_C\$ are wrong because they seem a bit high and i am also not sure if the formulas used are the right ones in this case.

[image]

$$ Z = j\omega L + \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{1}{R} + j\omega C} =11.57 e^{j62.16°}$$
$$ I = 19.02 e^{-j112.16°}A$$

corrected:
$$ U_L = I\omega L = 646.66e^{-j22.16°}V$$
$$ U_C = U_0 - U_L = 463.6 e^{-j189.36°}V$$

Comment: Some may feel otherwise, but currently we accept homework questions. If you think it is a poor one please feel free to ask the user to improve it.

Comment: Agree. Bad homework questions (showing no effort except cutting and pasting the original question) will get no or poor answers, clever homework questions that specify one or two things that are not clear should have the chance to get good answers.

Comment: Well, i think i showed some effort. The question is just not really wide-ranging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your \$\mathbf{I_L}\$ is correct, but your phase angle for \$\mathbf{U_L}\$ is wrong. An inductor's voltage leads the current by 90 degrees; you subtracted. The voltages are larger than the input because the circuit is reactive, but total power is conserved and you can check that \$\mathbf{U_q} = \mathbf{U_L} + \mathbf{U_C}\$ by cross-verifying \$\mathbf{U_C}=\mathbf{I_L}(\mathbf{Z_C} \parallel R)\$.

Edit: Here are the values I calculated with Python:

```
from math import pi, e    
w = 2 * pi * 636.62
R = 0.11e3
ZL =  1j * w * 8.5e-3
ZC = -1j / w / 10e-6
Z = ZL + (R * ZC) / (R + ZC)
U = 220 * e ** (1j * pi * -50 / 180)
I = U / Z
UL = I * ZL
UC = U - UL
IC = UC / ZC

def polar_str(x):
    from math import atan2
    angle = atan2(x.imag, x.real) / pi * 180
    return "({:7.3f}, {:8.3f})".format(abs(x), angle)

print('\n'.join(v + ' = ' + polar_str(eval(v)) for v in 
      [' R','ZL', 'ZC', ' Z', ' U', ' I', 'UL', 'UC', 'IC']))

output: (mag, phase)

 R = (110.000,    0.000)
ZL = ( 34.000,   90.000)
ZC = ( 25.000,  -90.000)
 Z = ( 11.567,   62.155)
 U = (220.000,  -50.000)
 I = ( 19.019, -112.155)
UL = (646.657,  -22.155)
UC = (463.659,  170.649)
IC = ( 18.546,  -99.351)
```

Comment: Ok, so i just have to swap the phase angle for $U_L$ with the one from $U_C$. Thought that $\phi_(Uc) = \phi_(ic) - 90°$

Comment: @madmax, $\angle U_C = \angle I_C - 90^\circ$ and $\angle U_L = \angle I_L + 90^\circ$. However, $I_C \not= I_L$ since the capacitor is in parallel with a resistor. The phase of $U_C$ is determined by the parallel impedance $Z_C \parallel R$. If you need $I_C$ you can use the current divider rule or just calculate $\frac{U_C}{Z_C}$.

Comment: When i calculate  $\frac{U_C}{Z_C}$, i get the same value and phase as $I_L$. Although i use $U_C$ and Z without $\omega L$. $I_C$ should be 18.5 A.

Comment: Thank you for the calculated values. The problem is my $Z_C$. My $Z_C = 24.38 e^{-j77.2°}$  $Z_C$ is just Z without $\omega L$, isn't it ?

Comment: @madmax, that's the value of $R \parallel Z_C$. The phase shift of an ideal capacitor is $-90^\circ$.

Comment: @madmax, the voltage drop across parallel circuit elements is the same, but the current through each branch will vary. Their sum is equal to the input at the fanout node. Thus $I = \frac{U_C}{R} + \frac{U_C}{Z_C}$.

Comment: Ok, my problem was i assumed $Z_C$ as $R||Z_C$. Now i got it! Thank you.